# SOLR Out of memor query for large row counts

Tags: java, solr, out-of-memory

SOLR seems to throw an out of memory error if I specify num rows = Integer.MAX_VALUE.

This makes sense for a large data set, but in my case, the query which I'm running only has one result. I assume then, that no matter how large the "num rows" parameter I send it, the server should be able to handle the request (since there is only one result in the return data set).

How does SOLR use the "number of rows" parameter as input ? Does SOLR try to preallocate memory before it runs a query ?

Comment: This question is more a general question about SOLR rather than a specific problem.  The solution to the problem is obvious --- but I'm more interested/amazed at the fact that SOLR can possibly through an exception when a result set has such a small number of elements..

Comment: if you do the exact same query but with rows=1 it works ok? Does SOLR throw an outofmemory exception or its your client (say SOLRj for example)? Your SOLR version and the stack trace would help as well

Answer (score 2):

In Solr 3.5, [SolrIndexSearcher](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_5_0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/SolrIndexSearcher.java) replaces the number of docs requested by maxDoc() in case of overflow, so this shouldn't happen.

If Solr actually tries to allocate Integer.MAX_VALUE entries, then this allocation is probably in the stack trace of the OOM. You should check:

- what method of SolrIndexSearcher is used,
- whether the SolrIndexSearcher source code for your Solr version tests the number of documents requested the same way as Solr 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ... I'll look into this.  Are you suggesting that its possible that SOLR preallocates the size of the result set ? That seems odd, but maybe there could be some value in doing so in "normal" scenarios when result sizes are small.  By the way, I'm using the Java serialized SOLRDocument query API, not the JSON one, in case that sheds some light on the situation.

Comment: I am suggesting that this shouldn't happen, but since it was your hypothesis, you should check that your version of Solr doesn't have this bug. And in case this bug is present, you should either upgrade if it is fixed in Solr 3.5, or report it to Solr developers otherwise.  We can help you cehck if you provide us with your version of Solr and the stack trace of the OOM.

Answer (score 1):

Never specify rows=Integer.MAX_VALUE. Retrieve the data in pages, and set a reasonable size for rows.

If Solr ever did return millions of rows, all sorts of bad things can happen, out of memory in the client, read timeouts while it calculates it followed by retries, and so on.

You might want to submit a bug for this, but this is essentially a bad behavior for bad input.

Comment: Your answer seems to imply that this is , indeed, a bug in SOLR. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I would expect it to either reject this as a bad input value, maybe with a 400 HTTP response, or ignore it and fix it. It appears that Solr 3.5 does the latter. Throwing OutOfMemory is not the right response for bad input. Still, doing this is a time bomb in your code, even if Solr accepts it.

Comment: I have to do solr dumps frequently and i set the rows=10M or higher. If the client runs out of memory, it's client fault, it has nothing to do with SOLR.

Comment: Again, this is a bad idea. Fetch the results in pages. Also, using Solr as a repository is not a good idea, for this and other reasons. You should never have to dump the contents of Solr, it should be in a separate repository.